# How to hard remove uninst.exe that is generated by NSIS?

Tags: nsis

I am using NSIS to write an installer for my windows application. After installing the application, an uninst.exe is also generated in my program directory. Later on I need to uninstall my program but I failed to do that in control panel. Therefore I went to the file system and tried to delete the directory. Everything other than that uninst.exe was removed. I've tried changing permission of this file and other methods but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

`WriteUninstaller` does not set file permissions or any other attribute that might prevent you from deleting it. It sounds like the file might still be in use by something on your machine.

Things to try:

- Use Task Manager or Process Explorer to see if there is a uninst.exe process still running.
- Use the find handle feature in Process Explorer to find any open handles to the file.
- Use [Process Monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to get detailed information about the failed delete operation.
- Check %LOCAL­APP­DATA%\Virtual­Store to make sure UAC Virtualization is not tricking you with ["ghost" files](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/927387/common-file-and-registry-virtualization-issues-in-windows-vista-or-in).
- Disable your Anti-Virus.
- Reboot the machine and try to delete the file again.